# Reversing the edges in directed weighted graph

Tags: java, graph, transpose

I am trying to reverse the edges in my graph small example, from this:

```
(1)---1--->(8)
 \         /
  2       1
   \     /
    v   v
     (4)
```

to this:                                                                 .

```
 (1)<---1---(8)
  ^          ^
   \        /
    2      1
     \    /
       (4)
```

I tried:

```
private static void Transpose(EdgeWeightedDigraph G) {

    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        // reverse so that adjacency list is in same order as original
        Stack<DirectedEdge> reverse = new Stack<DirectedEdge>();
        for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v)) {
            reverse.push(e);
        }
        for (DirectedEdge e : reverse) {
            adj[v].add(e);
        }
    }

}
```

any ideas please?

---

Update  1:

```
     private static Bag<DirectedEdge>[] adj;    // adj[v] = adjacency list for vertex v

      adj = (Bag<DirectedEdge>[]) new Bag[G.V()];
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
        adj[v] = new Bag<DirectedEdge>();
```

The output for my code is the same graph, my code does not reverse the edges

---

Update 2:
[EdgeWeightedGraph](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/EdgeWeightedGraph.java.html)

---

Update 3:

this is the right link: [EdgeWeightedDigraph](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/EdgeWeightedDigraph.java.html)

not the previous

this will be useful also [DirectedEdge](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/DirectedEdge.java.html)

Comment: I think that there is an issue with line `adj[v].add(e);` No idea where `adj[v]` is coming from. Please update code.

Comment: Would you mind adding the implementation for `EdgeWeightedDigraph`? Also, can that class change or does the solution have to be outside of that class?

Comment: Am I correct in surmising that the goal is not to change the original graph but instead to create a new graph with the edges reversed? Based on the source code you have provided and the implementation of the `Edge` class, I have my doubts that an in-place solution is what was asked.

Comment: It does not matter for me, Let's choose the easy way @entpnerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be a homework problem (let me know if I'm wrong about that), and you've stated what you've tried so far and what difficulty you're having, I'll give a high level solution, and leave out the code to do it.

Basically, you have to do is to get a list of the edges via the `EdgeWeightedDirectedGraph.edges()` method. Then, instantiate a new empty `EdgeWeightedDirectedGraph` for `V` new edges. Since the `Edge` type is immutable, you need to create new edges. So for each original edge you retrieved from the original graph, instantiate a new edge that has `v` and `w` reversed but with the same weight. Then, add that new reversed edge to your new graph. After adding the new reversed edges to the new graph, you now have a copy of the original graph, but with the edges reversed.

Note that this approach of creating a new graph is the most feasible because the `EdgeWeightedDirectedGraph` code doesn't appear to have a convenient way of removing edges, only adding them.

Edit: Adding some sample code as per request.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EdgeWeightedDigraph g = new EdgeWeightedDigraph(3);
    DirectedEdge e1 = new DirectedEdge(0, 1, 01.10);
    g.addEdge(e1);
    DirectedEdge e2 = new DirectedEdge(1, 2, 12.21);
    g.addEdge(e2);
    DirectedEdge e3 = new DirectedEdge(2, 0, 20.02);
    g.addEdge(e3);
    System.out.println(g.toString());

    EdgeWeightedDigraph gr = reverse(g);
    System.out.println(gr.toString());
}

private static EdgeWeightedDigraph reverse(EdgeWeightedDigraph g) {
    int numVertices = g.V();
    EdgeWeightedDigraph gr = new EdgeWeightedDigraph(numVertices);
    for (DirectedEdge e : g.edges()) {
        int f = e.from();
        int t = e.to();
        double w = e.weight();
        DirectedEdge er = new DirectedEdge(t, f, w);
        gr.addEdge(er);
    }
    return gr;
}
```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Cool. Comment further if you still need more help.

Comment: Can you add the code please( even if there is a small mistakes here and there)? The purpose of this homework is  not to learn how to program,  it's algorithms course. here it's a small part of the algorithm and I don't want to burn time on technical issues

Comment: Try adding this `main()` method to a class. It should illustrate what I'm talking about. Hope it helps.